# AJAX-PHP Requesting a local page secure?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security

Lets say I have this AJAX code that basically asks for a page in the website, for example:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST','somepagehere.php',true);
xmlhttp.send('type="ajax"');
```

Is this secure?, I don't see any security risks, but are there any with this piece of code?

Comment: post `login.php` as well..

Comment: Ups I confused the code, it should be:

<edited the code in question this one looked strange>
read what I responded to Mike W, it may also respond some question you might have about the code and its porpoise

Answer (score 1):

There are the same risks with this as there are with **any** client-side code: it can  be manipulated. You should regard anything done on the client as insecure, and verify on the server that you have what you should have.

Comment: Well basically it ins't much of a security risk the way I think about it (maybe I'm wrong), but the websites basically when you click a menu item instead of redirecting you to that page it makes an AJAX request that says "I'm being requested by an ajax form, don't post the style sheet, nor the header or bottom part, just the content" and if the page doesn't include that type='ajax' it basically just displays the website with the style sheet, header and bottom part.

This is mostly to make the website a bit faster, but could this have downsides?

Comment: Ancillary files like style sheets or javascript should be cached by the browser, so trying to avoid sending them is probably redundant. If you think they're not being cached by the browser when they should be, check your server configuration. If you're requesting pages and using a query string it is insecure. The query string can be manipulated to include anything. If your server-side script isn't bullet proof you have a potential security hole. [bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I'm actually trying to make my PHP code bullet proof, I try to make checks where I can to see its a valid request and stuff like that. So it should be ok for me to do this right?